# Transparent mac window renders double text

Tags: electron

I'm on mac Big Sur. And i create a simple window.

```
function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 150,
    height: 80,
    frame: false,
    // titleBarStyle: 'customButtonsOnHover',
    transparent: true,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: clientPath('preload.js')
    }
  })
```

Everything looks great, until i add the transparent flag. The transparency is working. However if i ever change a text from 'abc' to 'def'. Ex.

```
    window.addEventListener('paste', e => {
      let paste = (
        e.clipboardData || window.clipboardData
      ).getData('text')
      setText(paste)
    })
```

I got a update on screen that has the latest text to be in the right color but the previous text in a faded color, so almost that i hit a buffer render or something. I know it's a kool effect, but how can I remove that?

Also if I ever move the window around, the next update will fix the problem. This is not related to copy paste, when I change the text, it'll happen.

Comment: I don't know but maybe `hasShadow` has something to do, try setting it to false on the BrowserWindow options and check if it still produces that effect

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried your solution, it actually worked!! Amazing, seems the transparent mode is a kind of paint effect.

Comment: nice! I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hasShadow` may have something to do.

```js
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  hasShadow: false,
});
```

On the documentation: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions